# контрольная сумма для всей папки в терминале linux?

Tags: linux, хеширование

требуется сверить контрольную сумму залитых на сервер кучи файлов, которые находятся в одной папке. по сути без разницы каким алгоритмом, лишь бы сверить, чем менее ресурснозатратно и более быстро, тем лучше.
можно выполнить чек сумм прямо на папку? как?
например папка тут `/home/user/thisfolderforchksumm`

вбил  `:~/thisfolderforchksumm$ md5sum`- может конечно и работает, но что-то долго не выводит, а я для примера всего лишь два файла туда сунул (из 1000 нужных)...
ну или контрольную сумму на всю сразу группу файлов, находящиеся в этой папке одной командой?

как вариант - в filezilla нет функции сравнения именно по хешу? (просто сравнение каталогов знаю) 
сенкс

Comment: md5sum без параметров ожидает данных со стандартного ввода. он никогда не сакончиться пока Ctrl+D не нажмете. сделайте `md5sum *`

Comment: ок, спасибо, но md5sum * выкатывает суммы всех файлов, находящихся в папке, по каждому отдельно, если зайти в нее ':~/thisfolderforchksumm$ md5sum *'                                                                             
а как на всю папку? я как не прописывал, только ругается что директория.. как прописать на папку?

Comment: находясь в папке `cat * | md5sum` правда ему важен порядок файлов, а в каком порядке шел разложит `*` я не в курсе....

Comment: ок, спасибо! но ведь, если мне нужна полная копия всех внутри файлов и они все лежать подряд, то по идее ведь не должна контрольная сумма отличаться (какая разница как он их там высчитывает?) . ?

Comment: Я не понял, чем вас не устроил хэш для каждого файла отдельно?

Comment: "подряд" понятие растяжимое. Оно может быть в порядке записи в папку например, какой то файл позже скопировали и все, он последий. Или один удалили, который был первым, другой записался на его место ... Хотя такие нюансы от файловой системы зависят. Я надеюсь что все таки по алфавиту ...

Comment: to andreymal  - устроил, но в папке больше тысячи файлов, на каждый будет свой хеш. и как это сверять?

Comment: @Bl0wfish, для этого есть замечательная программа *diff*

Answer (score 1):

прочитать ([*fopen()*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html)+[*fread()*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) и т.д. и т.п.) можно содержимое **файла**, но что именно должно происходить при «чтении самого каталога» (1), насколько мне известно, не описано ни в каком стандарте (ну, разве что в [*plan9*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9) что-нибудь эдакое выдумали по поводу «чтения каталога»).

если вы принципиально не пользуетесь чем-либо вроде программы *rsync* для копирования и/или сверки актуальности копии файлов/каталогов, то, чтобы не сравнивать два списка с контрольными суммами (что, к слову, очень легко сделать с помощью программы *diff*), можно подсчитать контрольные суммы **самих списков**:

```
$ sum * | sort | sum
```

вместо программы *sum* можно использовать любую другую аналогичную программу: *cksum*, *md*sum*, *sha*sum* и т.п.

промежуточный вызов программы *sort* для сортировки списка контрольных сумм — на всякий случай. ведь теоретически оболочка может выдать список одних и тех же файлов («раскрывая» мета-символ `*`) в разных случаях в разном порядке.

---

если в каталоге имеются вложенные каталоги с файлами, и требуется получить и их контрольные суммы, то можно воспользоваться связкой программ *find+xargs*:

```
$ find -type f | xargs sum | sort | sum
```

---

(1) см., например:

- [c - fopen opening directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42876210/4827341)
- [plain C: opening a directory with fopen()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18192998/4827341)

Comment: exec для кого придумали, а?

Comment: @bukkojot, не понял вашего вопроса.

Comment: Ну у find есть ключик -exec, вот для чего его придумали, а?

Comment: @bukkojot, для данного случая использование *xargs* будет оптимальнее: эта программа сформирует максимально длинный список файлов и вызовет *\*sum* один раз для этого списка. а `find ... -exec` будет запускать по одному процессу для каждого найденного файла.

Comment: @bukkojot, к слову: https://stackoverflow.com/q/896808/4827341

Comment: Бубунта считает свои файлики в iso через `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum`

Comment: С максимальными списками бывает все очень сложно. Особенно если внутри директории больше миллиона файлов. Единственная причина, достойная упоминания, действительно находится по приведенной ссылке: Also lots of people do not know this "-exec cmd {} +", as you can see from other answers. И если уж так делать, то хотя бы экранировать имена. Приведенный пример как минимум не безопасен.